# sendJavascript not working in cordova latest version

Tags: cordova

I have application on android. I am sending String value from Java Code to JavaScript using the sendJavaScript API in cordova like below.

String js = String.format("function('%s');",Params);
MainActivity.sendJavascript(js);

It was working fine. But after upgrading to latest cordova version its giving build error for sendJavascript API

Can any one tell me how to call sendJavascript API in new cordova version projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call javascript like this:

```
((SystemWebView)appView.getView()).loadUrl(js);
```